# Request cancelled while waiting for connection in docker build

Tags: docker, flask

I am trying to dockerize my flask application.

I created a docker file that would create an Ubuntu 18.04 instance and create my server image.

my Dockerfile is placed in the flask application

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

EXPOSE 5007

RUN apt-get install redis-server

RUN pip3 install -f requirements.txt

RUN python3 main.py
```

When I run sudo docker build -t test .

I get the following error:

```
get https //registry-1.docker.io/v2/ net/http request canceled while waiting for connection
```

Some of the forums mentioned that I'd have to create a http_proxy in /etc/systemd/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

However, what is the proxy that I have to create here?  The documentation just says "some.proxy:port"

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Try `RUN apt-get update` before ANY `apt-get` commands

Comment: I think the issue is with downloading the ubuntu image itself.  I tried this and im getting the error.  It's failing at the first step

Comment: The forums and the docker documentation says you need to add a HTTP_PROXY.  But they dont define what proxy to add.  So im a little confused

Comment: I solved this error by usign user luxas's solution found @ https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22635#issuecomment-260063252